# How to get another proof of the separability of the linear functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed space and $x, y\in V$ with $x\neq y$. Prove that there exists a $g\in V^*$ so that $g(x)\neq g(y)$.

---

My proof is that apply the following Lemma

> Let $V\neq \{0\}$ be a normed space. For $x\in V$, there exists $g\in V^*$ so that $\|g\|=1$ and $g(x)=\|x\|$.

By this Lemma, for $x-y\in V$, there exists $g\in V^*$ so that
$$
g(x-y)=\|x-y\|
$$
So $x\neq y$, then $g(x-y)=\|x-y\|\neq 0$. Hence, $g(x)\neq g(y)$.

**Does this proof work?**

**Moreover, I would like if we can apply the following result to get another proof?**

> Let $V$ be a normed space and $Y$ be a closed subspace of $V$. For $x\notin Y$, there eixsts $F\in V^*$ so that
> $$
> F|_Y=0, F(x)=1
> $$
> and
> $$
> \|F\|=\frac{1}{dist(x, Y)}
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

The second argument would be to let $Y=\operatorname{span}\{y\}$. Then by the result you mention you would get $F\in V^*$ such that $F(y)=0$ and $F(x)=1$.

Both results are good examples of the power of the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Comment: Thank you! But how to show that $span{y}$ is a closed subspace?

Comment: It's finite-dimensional. Every finite-dimensional normed space is complete. More explicitly, since it is one dimensional, a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ would be of the form $\{\alpha_n\,y\}$; it follows immediately that the sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ is Cauchy and hence convergent whether it's in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Can we prove it as follows? Since $Y$ is finite-dimensional, then it is complete. Since $Y$ is a complete subspace of $X$, then it should be closed in $X$. I use one result that "The subspace of $X$  is complete if and only if $Y$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Yes, you can say it that way. Or you can use the more basic idea that a set is closed if it contains its boundary points. A boundary will be a limit of a sequence as above.